# Image manipulation-Difference Between 2 images

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-manipulation

I am trying to find the difference between 2 images using Opencv. The code is given below:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
char a,b;
cv::Mat frame;
cv::Mat frame2;
VideoCapture cap(0);
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout<<"Camera is not connected"<<endl;
    getchar();
    exit(0);

}
Mat edges;
namedWindow("Camera Feed",1);
cout<<"Ready for background?(y/Y)"<<endl;
cin>>a;
if(a=='y'||a=='Y')
{
cap>>frame;
cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_RGB2GRAY);
cv::GaussianBlur(frame,frame,cv::Size(3,3),2.00,0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
}

cout<<"Ready for foreground?(y/Y)"<<endl;
cin>>b;
if(b=='y'||b=='Y')
{
cap>>frame2;
cv::cvtColor(frame2,frame2,CV_RGB2GRAY);
cv::GaussianBlur(frame2,frame2,cv::Size(3,3),2.00,0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
}

cv::absdiff(frame,frame2,frame);


imwrite("img_bw.jpg",frame);

return 0;
}
```

The code is running fine but the output is not completely black and white like I want. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: since evidently you are capturing the image from a webcam or some other video source consecutive frames may not be exactly equal. Also, with the "foreground" and "background" being the two frames it seems natural that foreground will be different from background. could you elaborate on what you are aiming for a bit more?

Comment: Suppose the background is a wall and the foreground is a man standing in front of the wall then, the final image should show the man in white and the rest of the background in black. From what I have read, the difference between the images is represented in white and the portion which is the same is shown in black. Aiming for that.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense. so can you link to what sort of images you are getting? a perfect background subtraction doesn't happen at one go - you could try Morphological operations on the image to reduce false white patches, discard small white dots based on shape, area, etc.

Comment: Ok, hold on. Where do I upload it? Photobucket suits you fine?

Comment: upload and link here please, until you get enough repu to upload images on SO.

Comment: @AruniRC https://picasaweb.google.com/108898731668449364320/July132012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've given will output shades of gray corresponding to the difference of individual pixels between the two images. There will always be some small difference even between elements which haven't changed, just because of the noise or variability of the camera sensor. If you need purely black and white, you need to select a threshold where the differences are significant and convert every pixel below that threshold to 0, and everything above the threshold to 255.

Comment: Any links or any code that you can provide? And I'm trying to reduce noise using Gaussian FIlter. Why is that not working?

Comment: @PrakharMohan, sorry I'm not fluent in OpenCV. And reducing noise is not the same as eliminating it, I'm afraid that's not possible - and noise is not the only source of differences.